# How Detected Referrals Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to figure out a method to detect my apps downloaded through referral.
First thing I don't want to use any referral code enter by user. This is what I actually need:

1.Here is my referral link
http://affiliate.flipkart.com/install-app?affid=Inflation

(Where affliate/refferal Id is Inflation)

2.Now when someone download my app using referrals link so he will redirect to playstore.

3.After successfully installations how detect referral id in app ?????(without using user interaction)

Is there any google play service api to detect which link fall on playstore???

Actually there is app which doing like this but I don't know how it's works...
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update ( 30th, Nov 2017 )**

Google has introduced Google Play Store's [Install Referrer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html) to securely retrieve referral content from Google Play. I prefer to go for it henceforward.

---

> Using [INSTALL_REFERRER](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns) broadcast for Google Play Campaign
>   Measurement

1) Build a URL of your app in google play something like this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hello&referrer=tracking_id%3D123456789

or use

[google-play-url-builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#google-play-url-builder)

In which `referrer` parameter may have the unique value of campaigner.

2) Define a receiver in your app manifest.in which [`com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver) will help you to get a broadcast in the app when app installed from google play..

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.Tracker" android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

3) Broadcast receiver

```
    public class Tracker extends BroadcastReceiver {

          private String referrer = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                referrer = extras.getString("referrer");
            }
            Log.i("REFERRER", "Referer is: " + referrer);
        }
    }
}
```

After getting the campaigner details you can submit it to google analytics for [Campaign measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns).

You can test your app configuration running this command in the terminal:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER 
                       -n your.package.name/path.to.receiver --es referrer
                       --es referrer "EXTRA_STRING_VALUE"
```

For example if your package name is com.hello and the path of your receiver is com.ex.Tracker the test command will be:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER 
                       -n "com.hello/com.ex.Tracker"
                       --es referrer "tracking_id=123456789"
```

For [more](http://help.tune.com/marketing-console/how-google-play-install-referrer-works/) about working or you can also take a look at third party [SDK](http://www.invitereferrals.com/) which offers UI too but it costs..

Comment: ain't aware about flipcart technique, this is the official way which google prefer..

Comment: @AnoopM Sir.... Does it will also work on the already installed application?? plz help me... i have stucked in thes prblem...Thanks

Comment: Can i must need to add Campaign in my application?

Comment: Do you know how can be tested new approach with Install Referrer Library? without uploading to google play?

Comment: What is user not opening app from google play store immediately and after some time from app list?

Answer (score 1):

Recently Google released Google Play Install Referrer API to simplify referral retrieval process and make it more reliable.

Basically, now you have to 1) link library:

```
dependencies {
      ...
      compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
}
```

2) Establish a connection to the Google Play:

```
InstallReferrerClient mReferrerClient
...
mReferrerClient = newBuilder(this).build();
mReferrerClient.startConnection(this);
```

3) Get referrer:

```
ReferrerDetails response = mReferrerClient.getInstallReferrer();
```

More details: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/google-play-referrer-api-track-and.html

Comment: what's newBuilder?

Comment: ah it's method from InstallReferrerClient: InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder

Comment: can you please provide Sample Share Link with this library if you can.

Comment: Install Referrer API will return you whatever was provided to `referrer` param when Google Play was opened. It can be url, but also any kind of referrer id.